# How to overwrite the default shortcuts of the terminal in xfce?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I have xfce installed and use xfce terminal. I can't figure out how to overwrite the default shortcuts so that I can use Ctrl+C(V) for copy/paste in the terminal. So far in other desktop environments I've used it was pretty easy and intuitive. In xfce I simply can't find a way to do that.

Comment: You can still use gnome-terminal in your xfce session and set what you want with `Edit`, `Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Answer (score -1):

Use the mouse in the menu bar (If the menu bar is not visible, right click somewhere in your terminal and click `Show Menubar`) and navigate to `Edit`.
You will see entries for `Copy` and `Paste` with their currently configured shortcuts. *Right* click them and you will get a context menu where you can change them.

Alternatively, there is the [GTK+ way](http://docs.xfce.org/faq) of changing it by hovering the mouse over it and just hitting the new binding.

However, still being a good terminal emulator, xfce4-terminal is not the most configurable one out there. Most distros have multiple terminal emulators from various desktops in their packet sources. I suggest that you have a look at [Konsole](https://konsole.kde.org/) if you want more features and flexibility.

Comment: that's wrong...

Comment: What exactly ist wrong? I tried the first approach and it worked for me.

Comment: Edit is a menu and it has subitems. And there's no Copy-Paste edit shortcuts anywhere in xfce terminal.

Comment: As Xfce 4.10, the only way to change is by using the latter method (hovering mouse over and hit new keybindings). User must select "Enable editable accelerators" in `Appearance` > `Settings` - `Menus and Buttons` to do so.

Comment: This worked for me in the past only after enabling editable accelerators in SettingsManager -> Appearance -> Settings. But I can confirm it doesn't work now in all cases: in Manjaro 16.2 Xfce it doesn't.

Comment: http://docs.xfce.org/faq specifies a case where enabling editable accelerators could be done by editing a file (that I haven't found yet.)

Comment: At least for xfce 4.12 the comment from @clearkimura helped me. The important point is: not right-click, but just hit new keybindings! See also answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271150/how-to-set-ctrlc-to-copy-ctrlv-to-paste-and-ctrlshiftc-to-kill-process-in-x.

Comment: Xfce terminal has moved to GTK+ 3, which has no longer supports this feature. Changing keyboard shortcuts can only be done by editing a config file, see post https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12105

Comment: More than 100 dependencies for a terminal makes installing Konsole in Xfce the worst choice possible.