# How to set ctrl+c to copy, ctrl+v to paste and ctrl+shift+c to kill process in xfce4-terminal?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce4-terminal

Hello I can't find the option to reassign shortcuts in `xfce4-terminal 0.6.3`. I'd like to reassign <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to kill process. I know I can do that easily under gnome-terminal but since I'm using xfce I would like to avoid installing all the dependencies for gnome-terminal. Any idea on how to achieve that ?

Comment: You might want to consider konsole which is a lot more configurable than xfce4-terminal or gnome-terminal.

Comment: @Gray - People use Xfce to keep a light clean system, and installing `konsole` (and other KDE specific tools) in Xfce is **really** a bad idea, it comes with about 117 dependencies, while the added value is minimal. There are other alternatives anyway.

Comment: Minimum value? But Konsole supports output of pictures!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In xfce terminal go to `Edit`, hover your mouse over `Copy`and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Same goes for paste.

Kill process gets automatically reassigned to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>.

Comment: this is not working with xfce-terminal 0.8.4

Comment: I found that this worked for Alt-C but I couldn't get Alt-V to be assigned. Alt-T (for new tab) worked. Alt-A (for select-all) didn't work. I couldn't find the pattern. I ended up switching to konsole (++) whose shortcuts were assignable in the preferences.

Comment: The procedure you are describing belongs to GTK2 windows. In xfce that does not work. Understand that xfce could start gnome2 windows. So, you are probably talking about gnome-terminal, not xfce-terminal.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer doesn't work anymore (for example with `xfce4-terminal` 0.8.7.4 on Lubuntu 18.04.2) because of a GTK3 change, as described on [How to change key bindings for xfce-terminal?](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12105). It seems that the only way to change the keyboard shortcuts is by modifying the configuration file, `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm`.

It may be necessary to generate this file first as it's not included at installation: Terminal preferences>Advanced, select “Disable help window shortcut key (F1 by default)”. You can reselect it once the file has been generated.

Open the file, search for “copy”, and replace `; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/copy" "<Primary><Shift>c")` with `(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/copy" "<Primary>c")`.

That is: change the shortcut, but also **remove the semicolon at the beginning of the beginning of the line**. (It's a comment delimiter.)

[image]

The same for “paste”: replace `; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/paste" "<Primary><Shift>v")` with `(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/paste" "<Primary>v")`.

[image]

Restart the terminal.