# How to re-map keys so SIGINT and copy/paste are not confused

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macos, super-key

On my Ubuntu machine, in order to copy/paste from the terminal I need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, which makes sense, because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would issue a `SIGINT`.

Is there a way on my Ubuntu machine to make it so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is always copy and never a `SIGINT`? and to issue a `SIGINT` it would be a different key combo, like "superkey + <kbd>C</kbd>"?

The goal would be achieved if all terminal applications on Ubuntu would recognize <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as only a copy command, and superkey+<kbd>C</kbd> as they only way to issue a `SIGINT`.

Comment: Please don't [multi-post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207183/how-to-map-keys-on-linux-like-my-mac-machine)

Answer (score 3):

This should be part of your terminal. You can just map `copy` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> though in doing so you will likely lose the ability to insert `^C` with a shortcut.

Since keybinding are associated with individual applications I doubt you will find a solution that will cover everything system wide. I believe you would need to change it in the setting of all programs.

Answer (score 1):

Check here: [Remap interrupt command in terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271150/how-to-set-ctrlc-to-copy-ctrlv-to-paste-and-ctrlshiftc-to-kill-process-in-x)

Short answer:

```
echo $'# Make Ctrl+K interrupt command in terminal\nstty intr \^k\n' >> ~/.bashrc
```