# How do I switch <Ctrl+C> from interrupt to copy, and <Ctrl+Shift+V> to <Ctrl+V>, in xfce4-terminal?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, xfce4-terminal

This is basically the same question as
[How to set ctrl+c to copy, ctrl+v to paste and ctrl+shift+c to kill process in xfce4-terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/271150/80216), but not a duplicate, because neither of the answers helped. 
[Alex Kaszynski's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/271150/80216#509408) suggests modifying the
`~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm` file.

I did that: I have changed two lines:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/paste" "<Primary><Shift>v")
-->
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/paste" "<Primary>v")
```

and

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/copy" "<Primary><Shift>c")
-->
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/copy" "<Primary>c")
```

but neither of those helped;
the interrupt is still assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. 
(I would probably need to make it unbind and rebind
to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
but do not know how to do so.)

1. How to map "copy" from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. Remap interrupt from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
   to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Remap "paste" from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: If you change you key bindings to match every new, flavor of the month, windowing system that comes out, then you will be forever changing them.

Comment: is that lisp code. `;` is a start of comment character in lisp.

Comment: Alex Kaszynski's answer says "change the shortcut, but also **remove the `;` before the line**."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines to the `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm` file.

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/paste" "<Primary>v")
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/copy" "<Primary>c")
```

Note that these lines don't start with a semicolon, which starts a comment in Scheme.

Comment: But I now have 2 times copy and 2 times paste (from my original post, and from appended these two lines), should I have only your lines?

Comment: I would leave the two original lines and add the modified settings below them.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to anything else.
As is also a problem to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>. Those are setting so ingrained in linux (and Unix) that is almost imposible to make those changes correctly. I **strongly** suggest that you learn to use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Ins</kbd>     `# to copy`
<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ins</kbd>     `# to paste`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd>      `# Or shift-del also to cut`

All work the same in Linux **and** Windows.
There is also the Linux Clipboard which use other shortcuts.

---

Having said that, the changes needed are at (very) different layers.

The simplest to change (once you know where) is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> interrupt. It is usually a setting of the **TTY**, the program that control the communications at the line terminal. A very, very, old idea (from when terminals where replacements for ["Teleprinters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter)). The program in linux that controls that is `stty`, and `stty -a` will print the present settings:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 43; columns 93; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = <undef>; eof = <undef>; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = <undef>; stop = <undef>; susp = <undef>; rprnt = ^R;
werase = <undef>; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
.......
```

The setting for the interrupt signal is `intr = ^C` which reads: the key for interrupt is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (the `^` part) followed by the letter C.

There is no way in a TTY to use shift at the same time as control. There is only one encoded character <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> that is actually (because of the way control affects the bits of characters) the ASCII 0x03 character. To be able to write the require command to set `intr` you need to use also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>. The sequence needed to set it on the console is:

stty intr <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Or, if all other options fail, use the shell:

```
stty intr $(printf '\003')
```

That sets the `intr` to `^C`, there is no <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> at this level.

Also understand that if you change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> you need to change the way both the command `reset`, which returns the terminal to its default, or `stty sane`, which does a similar work; work.

## GUI (X-server)

At this level it is possible to set a hook to capture a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> key and being converted to a plain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to the terminal. But then, the terminal must still use a plain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

## GUI copy and paste

The sequence of actions to change the shortcuts for copy and paste is different for each DM (display manager) (Lxde, XFce, Gnome2, Gnome3, KDE, etc.). And it is also different for different terminals (Mate-terminal,xfce-terminal, lxterminal, Xterm, gnome-terminal, konsole, and many others).

In `mate-terminal` (a gnome application which could be installed and used in xfce without any problem) the sequence to change the `Copy` and `Paste` shortcuts is as descrived in the post that you report that doesn't work.

In `lxterminal` you go to edit-->preferences-->shortcuts and change any of them.

Finally, in `xfce-terminal` you edit the file:

~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm

Comment: Yes, but editting the file , it works. No I will not use gnome terminal since that is the reason I install xfce as default gui. No i will not use `<ctrl-ins>` or `<shift-ins>` since it  is very inconvenient for me, no matter unix reason. After all, all sequence I use is only after my preference, there could be old, sory - very old reason to use `<ctrl-c>` as intterupt control, but these time are forever gone, the world has changed, from times of teleprinters. You I am glad for the history rational, since after all - this is how I learn, so thanks anyway